# Adding years to Date (d-m-y) column In Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have datatable with Col1 with dates on the format (2019-08-19) and another Col2 with years in the format of ( 1 for 1year, 2 for 2 years ...)  the goal is to add the col1 to col 2 to new col with result of 2020-08-19.

I did if function but quite long I want simple and easy way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [Dateoffset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html).

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['col1'] + pd.DateOffset(years=x['col2']), axis=1)
```

Minimal Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['2019-08-19', '2019-04-25'],
    'col2': [1,2]
})
df['col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'])
df['col1'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['col1'] + pd.DateOffset(years=x['col2']), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0   2020-08-19
1   2021-04-25
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain why 1 at the end ?

Comment: @Gogo78, I have added the link for the docs in the answer. Please the edit. TO answer specific question, `axis=1` is used to `apply` a particular function for each row.

Comment: @Gogo78 when you see axis=1 it means to apply it on the row (in contrast, axis=0 means apply it on the column)

Comment: I don't why im still getting errors when I tried this TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Date' and 'relativedelta'", 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: other = other + self._offset
TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Date' and 'relativedelta'", 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Oh I fixed it thank you :) just wanted to know how only to keep date without hours/min/s ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple to follow method is::

Take column 1, split it by the hypen.

```
a = cell.split('-')
```

The first entry in the list will be a string of the year. Convert it to an interger, then add it to the value of the second column also converted to an int.

```
a[0] = str(int(a[0]) + int(col2cell))
```

Then recombine the values in the list with a hypen in between

```
newcell = a[0] + '-' + a[1] + '-' + a[2]
```

Do this for each row.